# lazy python on unix pipes

Tags: python, iterator, pipe, generator

I have a 4GB `big_file.txt`, so if I try:

```
cat big_file.txt |
python3 -c "print( open('/dev/stdin').read() )" |
less
```

My RAM blows up and I die. But if I:

```
cat big_file.txt |
python3 -c "
for line in open('/dev/stdin'):
  print(line)
" |
less
```

The RAM stands still, and I can scroll down, aparently reading the file on demand via `less`, even passing throught python. I can even process the line before printing, and everything works.

So I thought I could:

```
seq 1 100 |
python3 -c "
fib = lambda n: n if n < 2 else fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)
for line in open('/dev/stdin'):
  print( fib( int(line) ) )
" |
less
```

But this blows the CPU and I die again.
Changing `print` for `sys.stdout.write` and `sys.stdout.flush` makes it possible to at least watch the results in `less`, but even if i don't scroll down, the CPU keeps on 100%, aparently executing lines I didn't demanded.

At first I thought it's a 'reading block' thing, as if there's a minimum amount of data to be piped, so I tried:

```
seq -10000 100 |
python3 -c "
import sys
fib = lambda n: n if n < 2 else fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)
for line in open('/dev/stdin', 'r'):
  sys.stdout.write( str( fib( int(line) ) ) + '\n' )
  sys.stdout.flush()
" |
less
```

(Note this `fib` simply echoes any `n < 2`)

But still with no luck.
I also tried
`seq -10000 100 > numbers.txt && cat numbers.txt | python3 -c blablabla`

What's happening? Why it seems like in the `big_file.txt` example I can pipe on demand, and in the `fib` I can't?

Comment: Have you compared to the same logic without the pipeline involved at all?

Comment: ...which is to say: The algorithm you're running genuinely *is* slow in terms of CPU time with big numbers; `seq` has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Yes, I know, this is a minimum example of me trying to run cpu-heavy operations on pipes. I thought I could do it on demand, given that on memory-heavy tasks I can

Comment: What do you mean by "on-demand" in this context?

Comment: The point is, I want to understand how I can lazily evalute python over pipes, in the same way of the `big_file.txt` example. In my original use case I actually have a generator and stdout output, and I want to control the throttle on the pipe

Comment: Sure. Your problem here is with `less`, not with UNIX pipeline semantics.

Comment: yeah, but why I can control the throttle with less in the `big_file.txt` then?

Comment: In your first example, if there's 16KB of data read ahead by `less`, it doesn't matter in any substantial way.

Comment: In your second case, the CPU cost of that next 16KB (or whatever the buffer size on your particular system is) is *huge*.

Comment: I thought that was the problem, that less automatically demands blocks, that's why I tried with `seq -10000 100`, I thought I could keep the CPU at 0% if I didn't scroll down. Aparently you're saying the amount of data created by `seq -10000 100` before the critical lines (the ones containing x > 30, that will blow up the CPU) is still not enought?

Comment: This has nothing to do with I/O. Maybe you are expecting Python to process calls to `fib` in the background while you fetch the next line of input?

Comment: @Faccion, correct, it needs to be about 72-80KB to be enough (on my machine; see my answer which describes how that's measured, to be able to come up with an appropriate answer for yours).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The amount of readahead performed by `less` is much larger than what your CPU-bound test is optimized for. Try:

```
seq 1000000 | tee test.out | less
```

and look at the size of `test.out`. On my system, it's 80KB.

80KB of readahead for `fib` results will, indeed, blow out your CPU.

---

If you want to get an idea of pipeline buffering *without* `less`, you can do something similar:

```
seq 1000000 | tee test.out | { while read; do read </dev/tty; done; }
```

...which will tend to be somewhat smaller (on my system, 72KB), but still on most modern unixlikes nontrivial.

Comment: Nice, in fact I can `seq -1000 100 | python3 fib_pipe.py |  head -100` and it works.

Comment: just to close it, do you happen to know how I could either lower the buffer for less or use another tool to fulfill the final example? (ie, keep the at 0% on seq -1000 100 if I don't scroll down)